# Service error when running my Unit test

Tags: c#, wcf, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4, invalidoperationexception

I initially wrote a unit test to fail, now i have addressed the issue, but when i try to run my unit test again, i get this error

> System.InvalidOperationException : Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'InventoryManager.Services.IUserService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.

I have no idea why this is happening because I am using the same configuration in my Unit test App.Config as i do is my Service Library App.Config and the Contract names are the same.

**Service Library Project App.Config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="InventoryManager.Services.UserService">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:3637/Service.svc" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="InventoryManager.Services.IUserService">
          <!-- 
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
              automatically.
          -->
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <!-- Metadata Endpoints -->
        <!-- The Metadata Exchange endpoint is used by the service to describe itself to clients. -->
        <!-- This endpoint does not use a secure binding and should be secured or removed before deployment -->
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the value below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="InventoryManagerEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/InventoryManagerModel.csdl|res://*/InventoryManagerModel.ssdl|res://*/InventoryManagerModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=JUNIORLABOLD4A3\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=InventoryManager;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

**Unit Test Project App.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="InventoryManager.Services.UserService">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:3637/Service.svc?wsdl" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="InventoryManager.Services.IUserService">
          <!-- 
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
              automatically.
          -->
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the value below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="InventoryManagerEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/InventoryManagerModel.csdl|res://*/InventoryManagerModel.ssdl|res://*/InventoryManagerModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=JUNIORLABOLD4A3\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=InventoryManager;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: The `baseAddress` is slightly different, is that on purpose?

Comment: A unittest should be independent of any external resources like databases, services, etc.

Comment: Note that you have a WCF Service **Library**.  You will need to copy the `<system.serviceModel>` section from the library's app.config to the web/app.config of the application that is **hosting** the service.  Even the library project template includes an app.config file, libraries do **not** use it - they use the web/app.config of the application that is using the library.

Comment: @MartinMulder can you explain what makes my unit test dependent on the services or database ?... to my understanding, i am testing ma controller. It is the controller that makes a call to my services

Comment: Let me be more clear: A unittest should not call a database or service directly OR indirectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app config file for your unit test should have a `<clients>` section, not a `<services>` section.

Remove the `<services>` section from the unit test's config file, and replace it with the following:

```
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:3637/Service.svc" 
            binding="basicHttpBinding" 
            contract="InventoryManager.Services.IUserService">
</client>
```

The `<services>` section is used to define services for the service application, whereas the `<client>` section is used to define the service the client will be connecting to.

Comment: Hi Tim, thank you very much, this worked... I just have one question, regarding one of the comments above. "unit test should be independent of databases and services"... does having this app.config on my test project make it dependent on the Service ?

Comment: @ifelabolz - I'm not sure, as I'm not that experienced with unit testing (we just started doing them at work this year).  Your unit test by nature of pointing to the service makes it dependent, but I don't know how would you break that dependency.

Comment: A silly question here. Found this discussion trying to resolve the same error with my unit test project. Copying system.serviceModel from the tested project's App.config helped, but I wonder if this can be somehow automated. Is there a way to tell VS import this section automatically into unit test project? Or maybe there is a way to import it dynamically before a test runs?